# trying to create a table relationship with mysql v5.5

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

Hi all trying to create a relationship between two tables with mysql v5.5 Curious How I go about this...

```
CREATE TABLE posts(id INT AUTO_INCREMENT, 
title varchar(100) NOT NULL, 
body varchar(500) NOT NULL, 
PRIMARY KEY (id) );

//posts_id not null creating error?
CREATE TABLE comments(id INT AUTO_INCREMENT, 
comment varchar(250)NOT NULL, 
posts_id NOT NULL, 
PRIMARY KEY (id) );
```

I would like to have a posts_id in comments table share the relationship with the post table id in comments table.

Comment: What error are you referring to?

Answer (score 1):

You haven't set posts_id type:

`posts_id int(11) NOT NULL`

Then your comments table should look like this:

`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS comments (

  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,

  comment varchar(250) NOT NULL,

  posts_id int(11) NOT NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY (id),

  KEY posts (posts_id)

) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;`

And finally, a foreign relation:

ALTER TABLE comments
  ADD CONSTRAINT comments_ibfk_1 FOREIGN KEY (posts_id) REFERENCES posts (id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE

Comment: why would I put it like that? int(11)? this relationship needs to be foreign to posts table id

Comment: what about creating the relationship?

Comment: relation field must have the same type as field it refers to, so if posts.id have type of INT, comments.posts_id also must be INT

Comment: The `(11)` part doesn't matter. It's true the foreign key column must have the same type as the column it references, but the numeric option to INT types is only a hint for display width, it has nothing to do with changing the data type.

Comment: The `(11)` part was irrelevant, it's just my own habit to always define type and length in mysql

Comment: thank you the comments table worked. but after adding the foreign relationship I get confused on the foreign relation?  also when you say it it's just my own habit to always define type and length in mysql what do you mean by this? length of characters? what does 11 define?

Comment: i get error when trying to add the foreign key. ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CASCA
D
ALTER TABLE comments
ADD CONSTRAINT comments_ibfk_1 FOREIGN KEY (posts_id' at line 2

Comment: Thank you got it to work once I restabished the table I was using before I altered the table constaints...for some reason after I created the comments table I had to use database......again thank you sooooooo much!!!

Comment: Glad to help. The number in parenthes in case of int Type is rather Unused. Every SQL Client such as workbench or pma puts 11 in there, do i've just  gone with that. If you want to limit int size, use smallint or tinyint

Answer (score 0):

Give it a type, like varchar, or INT

```
posts_id varchar(20) NOT NULL
```

Comment: what about creating the relationship?

Comment: @user2129978 what do you mean by relationship? like a foreign key?  I do believe MySql does not use foreign keys.

Comment: @user1336827, see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/example-foreign-keys.html

Comment: by relationship I mean foreign key I believe. if mysql doesn't use it than how do I assign the relationship? I basically want the post_id on posts table to relate to the comments table post_id as it has the relationship shared

Comment: see the link from bill above.